# vtbl2 intrinsics on ARM64 missing

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, simd, neon

I have some code that uses the `vtbl2_u8` ARM Neon intrinsic function. When I compile with `armv7` or `armv7s` architectures, this code compiles (and executes) correctly. However, when I try to compile targeting `arm64`, I get errors:

```
simd.h: error: call to unavailable function 'vtbl2_u8'
```

My Xcode version is 6.1, iPhone SDK 8.1. Looking at `arm64_neon_internal.h`, the definition for `vtbl2_u8` has an `__attribute__(unavailable)`. There is a definiton for `vtbl2q_u8`, but it takes different parameter types. Is there a direct replacement for the `vtbl2` intrinsic for `arm64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the ARM NEON intrinsics reference ( http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0073a/IHI0073A_arm_neon_intrinsics_ref.pdf ), `vtbl2_u8` is expected to be provided by compilers providing an ARM C Language Extensions implementation for AArch64 state in ARMv8-A. Note that the same document would suggest that vtbl2q_u8 is an Xcode extension, rather than an intrinsic which is expected to be supported by ACLE compilers.

The answer to your question then, is there should be no need for a replacement for `vtbl2_u8`, as it should be provided. However, that doesn't help you with your real problem, which is how you can use the instruction with a compiler which does not provide it.

Looking at what you have available in Xcode, and what `vtbl2_u8` is documented to map to, I think you should be able to emulate the expected behaviour with:

```
uint8x8_t vtbl2_u8 (uint8x8x2_t a, uint8x8_t b)
{
  /* Build the 128-bit vector mask from the two 64-bit halves.  */
  uint8x16_t new_mask = vcombine_u8 (a.val[0], a.val[1]);
  /* Use an Xcode specific intrinsic.  */
  return vtbl1q_u8 (new_mask, b);
}
```

Though I don't have an Xcode toolchain to test with, so you'll have to confirm that does what you expect.

If this is appearing in performance critical code, you may find that the `vcombine_u8` is an unacceptable extra instruction. Fundamentally a `uint8x8x2_t` lives in two consecutive registers, which gives a different layout between AArch64 and AArch32 (where Q0 was D0:D1).The `vtbl2_u8` intrinsic requires a 16-bit mask.

Rewriting the producer of the `uint8x8x2_t` data to produce a `uint8x16_t` is the only other workaround for this, and is probably the one likely to work best. Note that even in compilers which provide the `vtbl2_u8` intrinsic (trunk GCC and Clang at time of writing), an instruction performing the `vcombine_u8` is inserted, so you may still be seeing extra move instructions behind the scenes.

Comment: You can't index `a` with subscripts, you need to do `a.val[x]`, but otherwise this solution provides the proper execution. My issue is that, it's now inserting an extra instruction each time I call vtbl2. This is in performance critical code (hence, assembly), and even without profiling, that makes me uncomfortable. It is used part of my shuffle 'emulation', which is used in all over my SIMD code.

Comment: I've fixed the mistake you pointed out, thanks. As to fixing the performance issue. Fundamentally a `uint8x8x2_t` lives in two consecutive registers, which gives a different layout between AArch64 and AArch32 (where Q0 was D0:D1).The `vtbl2_u8` intrinsic requires a 16-bit mask. Rewriting the producer of the `uint8x8x2_t` data to produce a `uint8x16_t` is the only other workaround for this. Note that even in compilers which provide this intrinsic (trunk GCC and LLVM), an instruction performing the `vcombine_u8` is inserted. With compiler support your performance concern would still be present.

Comment: So, as it turns out, I can go further up in the function, and have a combined version of `a` as you hinted at, which is a better solution for me that this because it avoids the vcombine. However, I think this probably answers the question as asked best. Also, just a side note: I've also update recently to XC 6.3, and it appears that `vtbl1q_u8` -> `vqtbl1_u8`. Thanks!